# How can I use the Date tools without requiring an end date?

Tags: 6, datetime

I used the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module's Date Tools (admin/content/date/tools) to add a date field to an existing content type. When I go to create a new node, it displays both a From date and a To date. When I go the Manage Fields section for the content type, I only see one date field.

Is there any way to make it display only a single date field when creating new content? I don't want to allow users to choose a date range, rather only a single date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an option to choose end date or only start date
try to make a new date field and in option before saving there is a check box if you want an end date or not
[image]

Comment: There was no option when I used the wizard linked from the tools page.